# NDVI from Landsat8 LandsatLook images

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, landsat, ndvi, multi-band

I have downloaded landsat image from this [site](http://landsatlook.usgs.gov/viewer.html) and now Im wondering if i can get NDVI index from it.

In raster calculator I have only 3 ranges, shouldnt be four?

Or am I doing something wrong?

If it helps its Landsat 8 sensor: OLI

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will *not* be able to generate the NDVI from **Landsat Look** images. These are generated from the visible bands to  ["simulate natural color"](http://landsatlook.usgs.gov/About.html)

In order to get the image with all bands, including *red* and *near infrared*, download it from another source - for example the **[USGS EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/)**

For Landsat 8 the NDVI is calculated as `(band5 - band4) / (band5 + band4)`.

Answer (score 0):

edit: No per answer above (I must have overlooked the image type)

---

Yes you can. I have no idea what's going on in that screencap, but you only need to use two of the bands in the calculation:

```
NDVI = (NIR - R) / (NIR + R)
```

SRC: http://landsat.usgs.gov/documents/si_product_guide.pdf

That's as specific as I can be without knowing which Landsat you are using.

Comment: If it helps its Landsat 8 sensor: OLI